# php mail changing salutation username in each mail, while using BCC function

Tags: php, email, bcc

I am using php mail to send mail to all members in a message thread when a new reply is posted.

```
            include('Mail.php');
            include('Mail/mime.php');

            // Constructing the email
            $sender = "sender@sender.com";                              // Your name and email address
            //$to= "" ;                         // The Recipients name and email address
            $subject = $Sname." has posted a reply";                                            // Subject for the email

            $html = "<html><body><p> DearMember, <br>    $Sname has replied to one of your posts. </p></body></html>";  
            $crlf = "\n";
            $headers = array(
                            'From'          => $sender,
                            'Return-Path'   => $sender,
                            'Subject'       => $subject,
                            'Bcc'           => $recipients
                            );


            // Creating the Mime message
            $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

            // Setting the body of the email
            $mime->setTXTBody($text);
            $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

            $body = $mime->get();
            $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

            // Sending the email
            $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
            $mail->send(null, $headers, $body);
```

Right now, I am addressing the recipient as "member". Is it possible to change that to individual usernames and still use the Bcc function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can either send the same message to all recipients using a long Bcc list, or you can send one personalized message to each user (calling `mail()` separately for each one), but there is no way to send a single email which differs for each recipient.